# Post feedback popups not localized

Tags: bug, localization, popups, post-feedback

When trying to downvote an answer on [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) (which I can't do because I do not have the required 125 reputation), the popup "Thanks for the feedback" is still in English:

[image]

I encountered the same problem on [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) and my sockpuppet on the [other](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) [two](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) international Stack Overflow sites (that's why I'm asking here and not on the respective metas).

Comment: On the sites that use Traducir (that is SOes: https://traducir.win and SOja https://ja.traducir.win at the moment) you can search for the string and mark it as urgent. That's going to send a web push notification to the users that subscribed to them.

Comment: Good to know! Since English is my main language here, it's not urgent for me.

Comment: "Urgent" is just a way of separating what's visible on the site from what's not (like developer story or teams strings). So if you see a string in English on an international site, it counts as urgent (regardless of how prominent it's displayed).

Answer (score 1):

Already translated for ruSO: [Не переведено сообщение "thanks for the feedback" для участников с репутацией менее 125](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7817/176217) (see [first revision](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/7817/1) for English text)

Hence there is no general issue anymore, but only locally site specific. Translation teams should translate that string by self for each site.