# Messages from the chat system are not localized

Tags: bug, chat, localization, transifex

On SO en español we found a message that is not localized and also not on [Transifex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transifex):

[image]

Is there a way to localize that string?

### EDIT (is not a duplicate)

The duplicate question not applied to this, since that string just wasn't localized <del>(is now localized on SO en español)</del> (we are in the process of localizing it).

The key for that (on Transifex) is: `90a0f41828b69ffe09588c741f067e7f`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post feedback popups not localized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313639/post-feedback-popups-not-localized)

Comment: [I've found the string](https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Thanks%20for%20the%20feedback) from the possible dupe question on traducir.win. So I don't think they are related

Comment: @KacosPro only us use Traducir for now.. so It's on transifex.. I will edit the post...

Comment: Yep, it's just that I always had some trouble signing in on transifex, so I was thinking that if it is there it will be on transifex :D

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296140/339911